I'm new to Google Cloud Platform and need some help in setting up projects in either BigQuery or in the SQL studio
I'm not able to locate a step-by-step guide within the Google Cloud Console on how to setup a project in BigQuery.
I have spent over a week in trying to setup a complete project in BigQuery and SQL studio and have used the google cloud shell but still not 100% sure on how to navigate the Google Cloud Console. I have viewed some older YouTube videos but most videos are at least 2 years old. The Google Cloud user interface has changed since those videos were published. Even the videos on the Google Cloud site are older.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
